# Суперлуние. Большая буква

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, слово "суперлуние" пишется с большой буквы или нет? "В ноябре мы станем свидетелями (С/с)уперлуния".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ноябре мы станем свидетелями **суперлуния**.

Суперлуние — это астрономическое явление, происходящее при совпадении полнолуния или новолуния с перигеем — моментом наибольшего сближения Луны и Земли.

Это не имя собственное, а название явления (как полнолуние или новолуние), написание со строчной буквы.